# Public Static is not allow to decalre Function or set Farpoint grid value

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, farpoint-spread

How to solve this issue, (Not allowing the declaration of any function in the Public static method, and also I can't set the value to the Farpoint grid) [image]

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to access non-static member in your static method. Maybe create a static field, assign fpsSubmitalLine to it and use this field in your method.

Comment: where is say FillElementList defined? I assume that also a static method? I don't see where you create a instance? Keep in mind you do NOT want to have ANY variables scoped to the class level for a static class in web land. The reason of course, public members at the base class level are shared by all users of the site - and thus code would be stepping on your toes so to speak.  but, you should be able to prefix that routine with the base class name, and then the method/property of that class (in this example FillElementList).